# iso image for qemu generation

Tags: image, qemu, iso

I tried to run this command for creating iso image for qemu

```
tar jxf arm-system-2011-08.tar.bz2.
```

But i got the following error

> bzip2: Compressed file ends unexpectedly;     perhaps it is corrupted? 
>   *Possible* reason follows.  bzip2: Inappropriate ioctl for device     Input file = (stdin), output file = (stdout)  It is possible that the
>   compressed file(s) have become corrupted. You can use the -tvv option
>   to test integrity of such files.  You can use the `bzip2recover'
>   program to attempt to recover data from undamaged sections of
>   corrupted files.
>
> tar: Unexpected EOF in archive tar: Unexpected EOF in archive  tar:
>   Error is not recoverable: exiting now. How do I resolve this.

Comment: like it says -- the bz2 file is porbably corrupted.

Comment: yes...how to solve this issue

Comment: Where did you get the bz2 file from ? If downloaded, then try downloading again...